# Add photo in laravel

Tags: laravel

I think I'm confusing myself here. I have three tables in my database users, profile and posts. Now I want to allow users to add photo so I added the photos table but in my controller instead of saying

```
$pho->photo_belongs_to=Auth::user()->id
```

I want to say that it belongs to a profile is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure why you have a separate table called profile. You can add all the profile information to the user table.

Anyway, yes it is possible if you specify the relations correctly.

User needs to have a relationship to Profile:

```
public function profile() {
    $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

Profile needs to have a relationship to Photo:

```
public function photos() {
    $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
}
```

Then you can connect the photos to the profile and user as follows:

```
$photo = new Photo;
$photo->profile_id = $user->profile->id;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for he response. You are so right why In the world do I have a separate table for profile I should just add it to the users table. That's makes sense Thank you so much man! You Rock!

Comment: Happy I could help :) Just to be sure, is the relation between the user and the photos clear now?